# Attempting to use Intent, to launch a new app and have the launching application automatically log in using new apps login credentials

Tags: java, android

I have an application that is currently set to launch another application, this new application requires login information to be entered before you can go any further in the application. The required login credentials are saved in the newly launched applications .java files. I want the original application to pull the login data from the new app (or just update the text fields with the data) and automatically log in without the user having to adjust any settings.

I'm new to Android development and very rusty on basic Java, I'm trying to learn and the best way I can is to look at some code that will do this or an explanation on what is required to complete a task such as this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When activity1 launches activity2, use startActvityForResult(intent) instead of startActivity(intent). When activity2 has the requested credentials, bundle them and return to activity1 (override the method onActivityResult() to handle the results).

Comment: Not completely sure this is what I'm looking for, when the original application launches the new app, I want the original to manipulate the new apps "login screen" enter login data automatically (by using the password saved in a .java file in the new app) and login essentially without the user even seeing the log in portion happening. Therefore, the launching application needs to automatically hit a "Admin Login" button input a username, password, email then click OK to close the login dialog box. Then and only then is the user able to interface with the newly launched application.

Comment: I also cannot alter the code in the "new" application in anyway, Activity 1 essentially has to do all the work.